# Knockout trigger computed observable before validator extension

Tags: knockout.js, validation, computed-observable

I have the following scenario - i have a property which has an extension which triggers a validator. The same property is also part of a dependant/computed obsservable. I need the computed observable to run first before the validator extension triggers, because it updates some values, which are required by the validator. However, the validator always triggers first.

In my model -

```
self.selected = ko.observable(false);
self.selected.extend({ checkVal: { viewModel: self } });
```

In my computed observable -

```
self.mySelectedComputed = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
              if self.selected()...//I do some updates here
        }
});
```

In my validator -

```
  ko.validation.rules['checkVal'] = {
    validator: function (val, parameter) {

        var isSelected = parameter.viewModel.selected();
        if (isSelected) {
            //some other checks here based on the values updated by the computed observable
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
    message: "Invalid.",
    decorateInputElement: true
};
```

Comment: Are ALL the values updated by the computed observables?  If they are then the validator should be called when ANY of the values are updated.  The validator essentially behaves like a computed.  Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/znnwozte/ for an example

Comment: Thanks! Nope, just 2 values are updated. What if the computed observable is sitting at a parent level? And it needs to trigger when any of the child "selected" observable changes?

Comment: Can you update your example to show all the other values that are updated, and as Artur mentioned, a sample app demonstrating the issue with something like jsFiddle or jsBin.  It really helps us to help you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are abusing computed observables. I think there is no way to explicitly define "order of update" for computed observables.

If in your validator you need some preliminary logic applied, maybe it will be easier to just run it there and do not depend on side effects from observable.

On the other hand: maybe this "update part" you do in your computed observable code can be expressed by set of observables in which case knockout would handle whole dependency chain. This is the usual and "clean" way of handling dependencies in view model.

Comment: I really want to avoid doing the update logic in the validator. I have 2 observables which need to be updated when selected changes. That's why i created a dependant/computed observable. How else could i achieve this?

Comment: Now you stated your problem differently (details matter). Can you provide minimal example on jsfiddle? I am sure pretty sure we can solve your problem but details you left out in your question may be essential.